# Java date parsing specific format

Tags: java, parsing, date

I wrote a little piece of code to expose my problem.

```
public class date {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println("The date format is : dd-MM-yyyy.");
        String date1 = "20-06-2012";
        System.out.println("The date1 is : " + date1);
        String date2 = "2012-06-20";
        System.out.println("The date2 is : " + date2);
        try {
            System.out.println(formatter.parse(date1).toString());
            System.out.println(formatter.parse(date2).toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like so :

```
The date format is : dd-MM-yyyy.
The date1 is : 20-06-2012
The date2 is : 2012-06-20
Wed Jun 20 00:00:00 EDT 2012
Mon Dec 03 00:00:00 EST 25
```

The problem is that I want to have an error raised when the date submitted doesn't match the pattern specified in the `SimpleDateFormat`, unfortunately, it looks like it sees numbers at the correct position in the string separated by the dashes so it makes it through. Is there another tool to do this or am I wrongly using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(boolean)` and set to `false`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to bypass SDF parse heuristics.

<sub>Then switch to [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) ;)</sub>

Comment: +1 for Joda-Time. For new applications it's also worth considering [JSR 310] (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen). Last I heard it's still on track for Java 8.

Comment: @ErikP I hope so; it's certainly been long enough :/

Answer (score 0):

As the other Answers say, you must define a formatter that fits your data.

## java.time

Java 8 and later come bundled with the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes that have proven to be so confusing and troublesome. This new framework is inspired by the very successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

Also, java.time includes a class [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent simply a date only without time-of-day and time zone, as you have in the Question.

The formatting patterns are defined in a manner similar to java.text.SimpleDateFormat, but may vary slightly. Be sure to study the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
String input = "20-06-2012";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDate : " + localDate );
```

When run.

> localDate : 2012-06-20

## Locale Not Needed Here

The [`Locale.English`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH) is not needed here, as there are no names of months or day-of-weeks in your data to be translated.

For more information about when to use Locale in parsing/generating string representations of date-time values, see [When is `Locale` needed for parsing date-time strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32162108/642706).