# Convert stream of Strings to stream of Longs

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<String>` that I would like converted to a `List<Long>`. Before Java 8, I would do this by looping through the `List<String>`, converting each `String` to a `Long` and adding it to the new `List<Long>`, as shown below.

```
List<String> strings = /* get list of strings */;
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
for (final String string : strings) {
    longs.add(Long.valueOf(string));
}
```

However, I need to do this conversion using Java 8 streams, as the conversion is part of a larger stream operation. I have the `List<String>` as a stream, as if I had done `strings.stream()`. So, how could I perform this conversion, similar to something like this.

```
List<String> strings = /* get list of strings */;
List<Long> longs = strings.stream().map(/*convert to long*/).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 16):

Solution was very simple. Just needed to use `Long::valueOf`.

```
List<Long> longs = strings.stream().map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

OR `Long::parseLong`

```
List<Long> longs = strings.stream().map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *"Solution was very simple"* So you found the solution in less than a minute and you weren't able to find it before you wrote the question?

Comment: @Tom I posted it as a Q&A. Stack overflow gives you the option to answer your own question as you post it. That way, anyone else that runs into this problem can see the solution without having to ask their own question about it. I had already solved the problem before I posted the question. I posted it for the benefit of others.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty obvious, but I wonder why you wrote your answer like you've done some research _after_ you've posted the answer and without any explanation apart from "Just needed to use `Long::valueOf`". Since you had the time for that. Take this as an example: [When is \`Locale\` needed for parsing date-time strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32162108). As an example: this post could explain how conversion from "Collection<A>" to "Collection<B>" works in general, what `.map` does and how `Collectors.toXXX()` determines the target collection type.

Comment: You think, converting `Long.valueOf` to `Long::valueOf`is not something that everyone who knows [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) will find out but deserves it’s own Q&A? Really?

Comment: No, I think that someone who doesn't fully understand method references may find this useful. Sure, the answer could be better by including how `.map` and `Collectors.toXXX()` work. If you have time to do that, that's what the 'edit' link or the 'Post Your Answer' button are for. Doing that would be time better spent than criticizing me for posting something that might help someone.

Comment: I doubt that this will help someone. Since you don’t explain method references, this answer won’t help that hypothetical reader who doesn’t know method references, on the other hand, there are already lots of existing Q&As related to that topic on SO which provide in-depth information. And SO is not meant to be a replacement for beginner tutorials [which also already exist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), by the way.

Comment: @Holger, while I agree with you, the answer unexpectedly got four upvotes, so it seems that other community members find this answer useful...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: there a are far worse postings having far more upvotes on SO. That doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: What about parseLong method?