# Splitting a list containing ; into another list

Tags: java, collections

I Have the below list which looks like below.

```
List<Integer> exa = new ArrayList<Integer>();
exa.add("1234567;345676;57689687;906986985689");
```

Desired Output:

```
List<Integer> newExa = new ArrayList<Integer>();
newExa.add("1234567");
newExa.add("345676");
newExa.add("57689687");
newExa.add("906986985689");
```

Now I need to remove the ; and add the numbers to the new list.Can you please let me know how to proceed forward.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `906986985689` will not fit in a list of `Integer`s.

Comment: This code never compiles. A string - e.g. `"1234567"` - cannot be added to a a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: [Convert stream of Strings to stream of Longs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32187159) `List<Long> longs = Arrays.stream(s.split(";")).map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

considering "**exa list**" as list of string, you can do it in the following way in java 8 and "**906986985689**" value does not fit into **int** category. Hence you can use long data type to achieve you scenario.

```
    List<String> exa = new ArrayList<String>();
    exa.add("1234567;345676;57689687;906986985689");

    List<Long> list = exa.stream()
                      .flatMap(a ->Arrays.stream(a.split(";")))
                      .map(Long::valueOf)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split(String regex)` method of Java's String class for splitting operation and can use `Integer.valueOf(String s)` method for converting to integer.

However, your current code cannot be compiled successfully. You have one compiler and one runtime error:

1. **The Compiler Error**: You cannot add String to an Integer list.
2. **The Runtime Error**: The 906986985689 won't fit to the integer.

By the way, for splitting a `String` into an `Integer` list, you can use a code something like that:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String s = "1234567;345676;57689687;906986985689"
String[] numbersArr = s.split(";")

for(String num : numbersArr){
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
```