# Error when trying to convert String to Datetime in Android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I'm new in Android and I have a problem with this. I want to convert this datetime string "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" to "HH:mm". Here is my string:

```
String date = "Mon Sep 28 19:49:26 GMT+07:00 2015";
```

I have tried to convert it like this but it failed and I couldn't see what exception was because `Exception e` always null!

```
private String convertDate(String date) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
        Date d = format.parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat serverFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        return serverFormat.format(d);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

So how can I get "HH:mm" or how can I convert it? Does any problem in my convert function?

Comment: how could the `Exception e` always null? That will raise another `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I try to use both ParseException and Exception. But when I using breakpoint to see what happen it always null!

Comment: Maybe you right. Seem Android compulse us to determine the Locale when we convert datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Locale

Set your [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to [`Locale.ENGLISH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH).

```
    ... = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    ... = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: WOW! It finally worked, thanks a lot! You've just saved my brain. haha

Comment: but I wondered that when I implement this method in eclipse it worked normally. Why I can't in Java Android?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess the Android has its own local due to zone when eclipse PC using ENGLISH local as defulat - just a guess

Comment: I thought it, too. But many many questions in StackOverFlow same my question but they didn't metion about Locale. They just give the solution in Console result not in Android app. That's make me very very confused

Comment: @JustinVăn You may find this Question, [When is `Locale` needed for parsing date-time strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32162108/642706), to be informative.